# Mac OS 10.13.5 - Dual monitor set up for MacBook with single USB-C

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, high-sierra, usb

I see that a lot of people are having issues with connecting dual monitors.

I currently have the USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter - with one HDMI cord and it works with 1 of 2 monitors. I also have a USB to HDMI adapter but it wont display the 2nd screen.

Does anyone have a solution to connect 2 monitors with the MacBook that has only one USB-C port?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I hope you find this site a valuable source of info/help. I just wanted to let you know I've edited out the second question as it was totally distinct from the rest of your question and this site usually works best on a one question per question basis. I've also added the extra info you provided in the comments. Should you need to further edit your question, there is an 'edit' option below it that you can use. All the best with your question!

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with the DisplayLink Driver and the macOS update 10.13.4.

From the [macOS page on DisplayLink's webpage](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/macos):

> Installing macOS 10.13.4 will cause DisplayLink connected displays to
>   go blank after the OS update when using DisplayLink driver v4.1.
>   Extended displays continue to work as expected in macOS 10.13.3, and
>   we can only recommend that you stay on macOS 10.13.3 or earlier if you
>   require this feature and have not already updated. Functionality such
>   as Ethernet and audio, where implemented, is unaffected.

You have to downgrade to 10.12.3 and the best way to do that is to revert to a Time Machine backup.  The second best way is to reinstall.  There's currently no way to roll back an update.